# encoding problem with QGIS 1.8 and CSV import

Tags: qgis, shapefile, csv

I have following problem with QGIS 1.8. Lisboa (standalone installer, Win 7 Pro 64bit) - I import CSV - text in CP1250 separated with ";" and using "," as decimal separator.

I correctly set the separated text importer, get correct point layer which has all text entries displayed correctly. I save this as shapefile, set the CP1250 encoding but when I load this layer in QGIS (choose CP1250 again during SHP loading) but get point layer with damaged text entries.

I use this tool for a long time and did not have such problems. Did you have encounter such problems?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Qgis 1.8.0 has a bug in correct encoding of shapefiles. Until this is solved, you can try this workaround in Windows:

Browse to `C:\Programs\Quantum GIS Lisboa\bin` on Windows XP or `C:\Programs (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\bin` on Windows 7. Look for `qgis.bat` and open it with a suitable editor (I have installed notepad++ for such things). After line 1, insert:

```
SET SHAPE_ENCODING=UTF-8
```

This will ensure that all entries are encoded correctly. Of course, you have to save the shapefile in UTF-8 to make encoding properly.

Or, save as spatialite database. There are no known encoding issues with that.