# Problem with encoding of CSV and SHP files in Linux

Tags: qgis, shapefile, csv, encoding

I am new to using QGIS.  I came up against the encoding issue of shp files.
This [solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33241/encoding-problem-with-qgis-1-8-and-csv-import) to solved my problem in Windows (for source I had to put windows-1253 instead of utf-8)

My question is what solution would I use in Linux systems where I have the very same issue?  Where can I "insert" a similar choice?

Comment: the same procedure isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you may use .cpg-files with encoding as additions to .shp (more on it [here](http://ssrebelious.blogspot.ru/2012/03/qgis-and-gdal19-encoding-issue.html)). Or hard-write encoding to the .dbf-header using Libre Office: just open it in Calc (it will ask you for encoding) and save it.

Comment: Thankyou!It DID save the problem! (one comment to anyone may read this:donot omit to choose the encoding in order to see the -corrected-characters)